# I Believe the Facebook SDK is Not Initializing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm, working on implementing the Facebook Login for Websites and have received a tremendous amount of help from @Darvex so far but as I'm trying to digest this in chunks by running one function (getLoginStatus()) but when I click the link to run this function, Noting happens.

The link titled "Login Using Your Facebook Credentials" can be seen near the top of the page, as well as  the code can be viewed via normal means.

The problem is when I click "Login Using Your Facebook Credentials" which calls: getLoginStatus(), Nothing Happens.

With my limited understanding of this code, I believe the problem lies with the JS SDK Not being initialized properly but I don't see anything wrong with the init code. (I havent changed anything but the App Id which I have tried with and without ' ')

if anyone could kindly show me what's wrong I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all in advance.

Here's the page in reference:
http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . login.php:54
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , login.php:126
Uncaught ReferenceError: getLoginStatus is not defined login.php:1

Comment: line 54 missing the php tags i guess.. 
<script type="text/javascript">var city = .$listing['City'];</script>

Answer (score 0):

From the Login Button I've exported from Facebook Developers, it doesn't look like quite yours. Check this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Try replacing it with yours. From what I've seen, I can for example alert something in the function that doesn't do nothing.

Probably it is not recognizing the Facebook library. Let me know if these changes would help you.

If you haven't created an Application (don't forget to replace the app id in the code I gave you!), [go here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

[For more about Facebook Login check here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/).